# Eclipse - Change problems view action

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I am currently working on eclipse plugin development. I am working with the builders and markers and I have implemented a rename participant where it checks for a valid file name (does not contain any special characters, lets assume a valid file name to be a alpha numeric regular expression). Its working fine when the user is working within the workbench. Say, when a user directly goes into the file system and changes the file name. I have implemented the markers for this case too. It will show problem marker for the respective file in the project stating, "Invalid file entered - {filename}"

Is there any possibility to change the action on clicking the respective problem marker in the problems view. Say, if such a rename problem marker comes I want to open the rename resource dialog instead of opening the respective file on clicking the problem in the view. Any help upon that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although this does not change the double-click behaviour of the marker, you could provide a Quick Fix for the user as described in the Eclipse [marker resolution help](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/guide/wrkAdv_markerresolution.htm), and display the rename resource dialog from within the IMarkerResolutionGenerator you provide.

Comment: That's exactly how Eclipse wants this to be implemented, therefore I also recommend this way.